# Strange behavior when reading and writing "float" and "double" types in C

Tags: c, types, double

When I put 1 for example this return 1.000 (that's fine to me):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    float num;

    printf("Double: ");
    scanf("%f", &num);

    printf("%f\n", num);
}
```

So, when I put 1 at this it returns 0.000. I don't understand because I used %f to read and write correctly. Can you guys explain me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    double num;

    printf("Double: ");
    scanf("%f", &num);

    printf("%f\n", num);
}
```

Comment: Use `scanf("%lf", ...)`  for `double`s

Comment: `%f` in `printf()` prints a `double`, and `float` is promoted to `double` when passed to it.  However, `%f` for `scanf()` is for scanning `float`, and doesn't normally work for `double`... try `%lf`

Comment: My book doesn't show this, but still is a good book for beginners in C. Thanks you guys and I'm sorry for the duplicated question.